# Vue element-io collapsed side-menu problem

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I am trying to implement a simple admin panel using [Element UI](https://element.eleme.io/) library.

My problem is that when sidemenu is hidden, the content does not occupy 100%, and the only way to fix it is to disable menu animation and force its width to be smaller when collapsed using CSS:

```
aside.menu-collapsed {
    width: 64px !important;
}
```

[image]

My layout looks like this:

**Template:**

```
<template>
    <el-container>
        <el-aside v-bind:class="[isCollapse ? 'menu-collapsed' : 'menu-expanded']">
            <el-menu :router="true"
                     :default-active="$route.path"
                     :collapse="isCollapse"
                     :collapse-transition="true"
                     class="el-menu-vertical"
            >

                <template v-for="rule in routes">
                    :
                    :
                </template>
            </el-menu>
        </el-aside>

        <el-container>
            <el-header height="100">
                <span v-on:click="collapseSidebar()">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </span>
            </el-header>

            <el-main>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </el-main>

        </el-container>
    </el-container>
</template>
```

**Css:**

```
<style>
.el-menu-vertical {
    height: 100vh;
}
.el-menu-vertical:not(.el-menu--collapse) {
    width: 100%;
}

.el-header {
    background-color: #b4bbc1;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 56px;
}
</style>
```

Any idea how can I make the content width grow when collapsing the sidemenu?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

`<el-aside :span="4"  v-bind:style='{"width": (isCollapse? "64px" : "300px" )}'>`
.
.

```
<span @click="isCollapse = !isCollapse"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
```